# What is the purpose of <payment_action> tag in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm new to magento and i'm trying to understand the tags in creating a custom payment module. I just want to ask what is the purpose of payment_action tag in magento

Here is my xml code for payment

```
<default>
<payment>
  <paymentmodule>
    <active>1</active>
    <model>paymentmodule/paymentmethod</model>
    <order_status>pending</order_status>
    <title>Custom Payment Module</title>
    <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
    <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
  </paymentmodule>
</payment>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you integrate or use a Payment method that uses 3rd party API or redirects on merchnat website for payment processing, there are two modes for payment (Payment Action):

1. Authorize
2. Capture OR Sale

The XML snippet that you mentioned above is to set default value in payment method system configuration in `payment_action` field as `sale`. so that amount will be deducted instantly when user place order instead of authorize only.